# Get array values from an option select with javascript to populate text fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where the user can make an "instant search" with ajax, and the search result are shown as "select... option" tags, when the user choose an option, it's value will populate a text field. The "simplified" version of the code is this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    Code: <input type="text" name="Code" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    <select class="paselect" onchange="form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="2413">2413 - Name A</option>
        <option value="2414">2414 - Name B</option>
        <option value="2415">2415 - Name C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You can also check it on line: http://jsfiddle.net/BCXfQ/

Now, I need to get TWO values for each option select, like this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    Code: <input type="text" name="Code" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    <select class="paselect" onchange="form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="['Name A', '2413']">2413 - Name A</option>
        <option value="['Name B', '2414']">2414 - Name B</option>
        <option value="['Name C', '2415']">2415 - Name C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But I don't know how to get the array values and populate the two fields one with Code and the other with Name.

Online: http://jsfiddle.net/zm3nX/

I tried since now to change

```
form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

to

```
form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value[0]
```

and to

```
form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex[0]].value
```

but with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: BTW, `form1.elements['Code'].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;` can be `this.form.Code.value = this.value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<script>
function updateValues(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  var v = el.value;
  v = v.replace(/^\[\'|\'\]$/g,'').split("', '");
  form.Code.value = v[1];
  form.Name.value = v[0];
}
</script>

<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  Code: <input type="text" name="Code" size="32" readonly> <br>
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" size="32" readonly> <br>
  <select class="paselect" onchange="updateValues(this);">
    <option value="['Name A', '2413']">2413 - Name A
    <option value="['Name B', '2413']">2413 - Name B
    <option value="['Name C', '2413']">2413 - Name C
  </select>
</form>
```

Note that in IE if the user navigates the options using the cursor keys, an onchange event will be dispatched every time they move focus to a different option. Other browsers will wait for an option to actually be chosen with tab or space (depending on the browser).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried it but seems not working http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Mck/

Comment: Actually this is working good! I don't know why in jsfiddle is not working but when I did the exact same thing in local it worked perfectly in IE and FF. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using data attributes instead?

```
Code: <input type="text" id="foo-code" name="Code" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
Name: <input type="text" id="foo-name" name="Name" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
<select class="paselect" id="foo-list">
  <option data-name="Name A" data-code="2413">2413 - Name A</option>
  <option data-name="Name B" data-code="2413">2413 - Name B</option>
  <option data-name="Name C" data-code="2413">2413 - Name C</option>
</select>
```

and glue things together:

```
var select = document.getElementById("foo-list");
var code = document.getElementById("foo-code");
var name = document.getElementById("foo-name");
select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  code.value = this.getAttribute("data-code");
  name.value = this.getAttribute("data-name");
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tryed your script too but seems not working: http://jsfiddle.net/xtSqh/

Comment: I re-tried your script also in local after jsfiddle and still not working in IE or FF. Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I never condisered to use data attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I'd take an approach similar to the way Angular does this - using jquery with rodneyrehm's example:

```
<select class="paselect" id="foo-list">
  <option data-name="Name A" data-code="2413">2413 - Name A</option>
  <option data-name="Name B" data-code="2413">2413 - Name B</option>
  <option data-name="Name C" data-code="2413">2413 - Name C</option>
</select>

$('#foo-list').change(function() {
    var opt = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
    var name = opt.attr('data-name');
    var code = opt.attr('data-code');

    $('#status').text('Name: ' + name + ', Code: ' + code);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/mbSLB/

This avoids the potentially flimsy regex; strings you store and what to escape when become simpler to consider and error check.

The `data-` prefix is just there to comply with the HTML5 spec, but the truth is you can make up whatever attribute names you like - so if you were generating this HTML on the server and wanted to keep it short you could even use `a=` and `b=`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
<script>
    function setdata(selectvalue, selecttext){  
        form1.elements['Code'].value = selectvalue;
        form1.elements['Name'].value = selecttext;
    }
</script>

<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    Code: <input type="text" name="Code" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    <select class="paselect" onchange="setdata(this.value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
         <option value="['Name A', '2413']">2413 - Name A</option>
         <option value="['Name B', '2414']">2414 - Name B</option>
         <option value="['Name C', '2415']">2415 - Name C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, I tried your solution too but seems not working: http://jsfiddle.net/tyfQ2/

Comment: Yes I tryed also in local after jsfiddle, it is working but not as asked, in fact I get "['Name B', '2414']" in the Code textfield and "2414 - Name B" in the Name textfield, it should be Code = 2414, Name = Name B. But thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    Code: <input type="text" name="Code" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="32" readonly="readonly" /> <br />
    <select class="paselect" onchange="getValue(this.value);">
        <option value="Name A-2413">2413 - Name A</option>
        <option value="Name B-2413">2413 - Name B</option>
        <option value="Name C-2413">2413 - Name C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    function getValue(val){ 
        var myval=val.split('-');
        form1.elements['Code'].value=myval[1];
        form1.elements['Name'].value=myval[0];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's a great solution too!